# Make RabbitMQ durable/persistent queues survive Kubernetes pod restart

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, persistence, persistent-storage

Our application uses RabbitMQ with only a single node. It is run in a single Kubernetes pod.

We use durable/persistent queues, but any time that our cloud instance is brought down and back up, and the RabbitMQ pod is restarted, our existing durable/persistent queues are gone.

At first, I though that it was an issue with the volume that the queues were stored on not being persistent, but that turned out not to be the case.

It appears that the queue data is stored in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/<user@hostname>`. Since the pod's hostname changes each time, it creates a new set of data for the new hostname and loses access to the previously persisted queue. I have many  sets of files built up in the mnesia folder, all from previous restarts.

How can I prevent this behavior?

The closest answer that I could find is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892531/messages-dont-survive-pod-restarts-in-rabbitmq-autocluster-kubernetes-installat), but if I'm reading it correctly, this would only work if you have multiple nodes in a cluster simultaneously, sharing queue data. I'm not sure it would work with a single node. Or would it?

Comment: RabittMQ specific settings:
[Durability](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html)
Durable queues are persisted to disk and thus survive broker restarts. Queues that are not durable are called transient.
Durability of a queue does not make messages that are routed to that queue durable. __If broker is taken down and then brought back up, durable queue will be re-declared__ during broker startup, __however, only persistent messages__ will be recovered. __This is done via a message property__ (delivery_mode or, in some clients, persistent).

Comment: @JoeMjr2 Were you able to resolve this? :)

Answer (score 3):

What helped in our case was to set `hostname: <static-host-value>`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  ...
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        ...
      hostname: rmq-host
```

Comment: where did you added the `hostname`?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent this behavior?

By using a [`StatefulSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) as is intended for the case where Pods have persistent data that is associated with their "identity." [The Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq#rabbitmq) is a fine place to start reading, even if you don't end up using it.

Comment: This is probably the better solution but it might be useful to provide a bit more detail as to how to achieve this with these methods.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself and the quickest way I found was to specify an environment variable RABBITMQ_NODENAME = "yourapplicationsqueuename" and making sure I only had 1 replica for my pod.